# Any ideas how to fix "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred" when attempting to connect to Oracle DB?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database using asp.net.

I have tns.ora entries set up correctly (I believe) in web.config file as shown below:

```
<add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myServiceName)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"/>
```

Then I use the connection string in codebehind:

```
Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
```

I declared Oracle Connection:

```
Imports System.Data.OracleClient
```

First, I am getting an error that

```
Namespace or Type declared in Imports System.Data.OracleClient
 doesn't contain any public member or is not found
```

When I removed it, I got the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible...

I *think* that this has to do with Imports statement.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Private Sub PopulateContinents()
    Dim oOracleConn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection()
    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString

```
Dim strQuery As String = "select deptID, DeptName from Dept"
Dim con As OracleConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
Dim cmd As OracleCommand = New SqlCommand
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = strQuery
cmd.Connection = con
oOracleConn.Open()
ddlContinents.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
ddlContinents.DataTextField = "deptID"
ddlContinents.DataValueField = "DeptName"
ddlContinents.DataBind()
con.Close()
```

End Sub

Comment: The error is saying that it can't connect to the database, which usually means that your connection string is not right, e.g. you are connecting to a no existent server or many other potential issues.

Comment: The server does exist. The connection string works perfectly in classic ASP. I tweaked a little for asp.net. So, yes the server does exist and connection string I believe, as state, is correct. It is the imports that I have suspicion may not be connect.

Comment: What KIND of connection are you using?  Reading for a second time the error is referring to an MS SQL connection, so it looks like it is trying to connect to an MS sql DB with your connection string details.  Post your code that is making the connection.

Comment: You said EXACTLY the point I have been trying to make and that is that while the web.config file contains Oracle connection string, my declaration appears to be pointing to SQL Server but needs to point to Oracle but I am not sure how to fix that. I will post more code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that the application is not getting the correct connection string.

First, try to clear all connection strings in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="...
```

Second, try to specify the provider you want to use:

```
<add name="your.cs.name"
   providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
   connectionString="Data Source=//server:1521/instancename;User ID=UID;Password=PASS" />
```

Comment: Do  i need to install this provider? It is still not working. same namespace error.

Comment: Yes you would need the Oracle providers. Does the "network-related" error solved?

Comment: No, I can't even compile the app anymore.

It is my understanding that you use Oracle.DataAccess.Client only for Oracle 10g or later?

We are still using Oracle 9i

Comment: On Oracle pages there are a 9i ODAC packages. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

Comment: Are you using the ASP.Net membership providers? Open IIS manager, go to the directory properties (IIS 5 or 6) and on ASP.Net tab, show configurations, here is a list of connections strings. Generaly the first appoint to a SQLServer but it can be deactivated. IIS7.5 have a item named "Connection Strings" in the front page.

Comment: sorry for late response.

No, I am not using membership providers.

Will your instruction still work?

Comment: I made some tips based on my experience with oracle connections, to assist you in solving the problem. If you thought the primary problem was solved, you can mark the answer as correct. If another error ocurred after, I suggest opening another topic specifying the problem. You can start a blank application just for testing the connectivity. I only suggest to deal with Oracle Providers if you have some knowledge about oracle installers.

Comment: You have not provided anyting that helped me solve the problem yet.

The fundamental problem is that I am not using Oracle Providers. You recommended 9i which I downloaded but there is no Oracle dataAccess dll in it.
If you have the dll, point me to where I can get it. Then I can mark this question as answered.